# Scan Javascript for abusive functions and patterns

Tags: javascript, regex, function

We have an OpenSource Extension Similar like Greasemonkey *only used in Firefox*.
Users can submit (Java)scripts for other Users to run.
*This gets abused by sending malicious code.*

We want to rough autocheck in future with a script the submitted Code.

**We don't allow** or want to further investigate:

- **making page requests**
- **obfuscation attempts**

**We already filter:**

- btoa
- eval
- window.
- a regex for url's
  /^(http|https|ftp)://([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(\d+)?/?/i
- the above url regex adjusted for escape,encode,encodeURI,encodeURIComponent v.versa

**What could help:**

- **other possible bad patterns & functions**
- **a regex to filter for obfuscation attempts**

Thank you for your ideas !!

**EDIT:**

I guess this is it so far. Thanks to every contributor !
Would be welcome though to find a broadly valid regex to filter for **already** obfuscated code.

Comment: No matter what you scan for, someone will find a way around it. `unescape('malicious code here')` and `[][+[]]` tricks will likely get by your filter.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I recently (a year ago?) read an article about someone doing something similar - and how they were able to nail down a lot of these problems... I'd be curious if anyone finds/knows about the article.

Comment: @zzzzzBov thank you. we adjusted the url regex to work also for escape,encode,encodeURI,encodeURIComponent and their contreparts. I should have set more emphasize on the word "rough" autocheck. we know its likely impossible to scan for all obfuscation attempts but we would love to cover some that the script kiddies use.

Comment: `Function` and `document.write(ln)` are forms of `eval`.

Comment: @rob its Firefox only. i assume you mean the 2 Points under 'What could help'. the regex to filter for obfuscation attempts is the key. we can search the code for functions that generate obfuscation OR, and i think it might be successfull as well, detect the already obfuscated code in the script. thx for the CW i liked much :)

Comment: @Rob W i already wrote that i the inital question since its a firefox addon. Something to consider: Lot users write obfuscation functions themself in the code and then apply them to already obfuscated code or even use them to reorder the code for different purposes. Some others do use already obfuscated code. its really versatile.

Comment: Did you look at Caja, which has a similar use-case  http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/

Comment: @Jim Blackler +1 for the suggestion. Unfortunately its in java

Comment: @JimBlackler - Hey! That's it!! That's what I had seen.

Comment: @Steve good2know. some patterns of caya can easy be transported to any language since its well written. i will see if its worth to fork at git for some kind of javascript detection lib.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Community wiki

Add any ideas you have, and *keep in mind that it is a **rough check***.

**Tip beforehand:** Also run the code through [Google's Closure compiler](http://closure-compiler.appspot.com/home), to easily get rid off constructs like `window['e'+'v'+'a'+l]('....')` and character escape sequences like `\x65\x76\x61\x6c`.

Do not only check for functional hazards. For example, [typed arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript_typed_arrays) are an easy method to fill the memory with junk, causing instabilities at the user's OS. If the volume of scripts permit it, I recommend to test the script in a sandbox, e.g. in a VM.

```
window.pollute = new ArrayBuffer(2e9); // Reserves 2 GB of memory
while(1);                              // Infinite loops
```

Global objects (any permutation of these):

- **`window`**
- **`document.defaultView`**
- **`top`**
- **`parent`**
- **`frames`**
- **`self`**
- **`content`**

Other:

- The **`Function`** constructor and **`setTimeout`** / **`setInterval`** with a string argument - Eval in disguise
- **`document.createElement`** - Possibly injecting code or external resources.
- **`cloneNode`** / **`appendChild`** / **`replaceChild`** / **`insertBefore`** - Dangerous when combined with dynamic elements.
- **`document.scripts`** - Basically any DOM manipulation!
- **`document.cookie`** / **`localStorage`** / **`globalStorage`**
- **`XMLHttpRequest`**
- **`document.forms`** - HTTP requests
- **`document.anchors`** / **`document.links`** - Spoofing links?
- **`document.applets`** / **`document.embeds`** / **`document.plugins`**
- **`document.load`** - Loads a (XML) document
- **`document.execCommand`** - Executes a command on the current document
- **`Image`** / **`Audio`** - HTTP requests
- **`open`** (pop-ups)
- **`document.open`** / **`document.write`** / **`document.writeln`** - Replacing or injecting arbitrary data in the current page
- **`innerHTML`** / **`outerHTML`** - Same as previous one (`outerHTML` does not exist in FF)
- [Many events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/DOM_event_reference) plus `setAttribute`, `addEventListener` etc.
- **`Worker`** - Loading web workers from external sources (!)
- **`location`** / **`document.URL`** - Changing the page's location
- **`history`** - History / location manipulation (!)
- **`document.implementation`** - Creating arbitrary documents.
- **`DOMParser`** - Creating arbitrary documents.
- **`Object.defineProperty`** / **`__defineGetter__`** / **`__defineSetter__`** etc.
- **`WebSocket`** / **`MozWebSocket`**
- **`console`** or any property thereof
- **`debugger`** statement - acts like a breakpoint for debugging purposes
- **`InstallTrigger`** - A Firefox-specific object [to manage installs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XPInstall_API_Reference/InstallTrigger_Object).
- **`File`** / **`FileReader`** / **`FormData`** / **`MozBlobBuilder`**
- **`Packages`** / **`java`**

**Obfuscation**

.. detection can be done in 2 ways (searching the functions or the output).

Search for obfuscation Functions:

- **`unescape`** / **`escape`**
- **`encodeURIComponent`** / **`decodeURIComponent`**
- **`encodeURI`** / **`decodeURI`**
- **`btoa`** / **`atob`**
- `/\\x[0-9a-f]{2}|\\u\d{4}/i` - Pattern to match encoded characters.
- HTML entities (in conjunction with event attributes).

Search for obfuscation Output:

- **Regex to search for strings greater than X, eg 23**   `[^']{23,}`?

Comment: This list is far from complete. I made this post CW to encourage edits.

Comment: do you know offhand if closure compiler handles unicode escape sequences like `\u0065`?

Comment: also how to handle things like `img = document.createElement('img'); img.onload = (...nasty stuff...)`?

Comment: @GGG Known characters are converted (`\u65` -> `e`), `\x12` is replaced with `\u0012`. As for image: That's handled by marking `document.createElement` as suspicious.

Comment: nice 2 read http://www.defcon.org/images/defcon-16/dc16-presentations/defcon-16-kolisar.pdf